# PowerMockito.doReturn returns null

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

This is my class under test:

```
public class A {

public Integer callMethod(){
  return someMethod();
}


private Integer someMethod(){
  //Some Code
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(oAuthMessage.URL);
  //Some Code
  HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost); ------1
  Integer code = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); ---2
  return code;
}
```

Now I want to mock the line 1 & 2 & return a mock HttpResponse & code.

I have tried this but failed:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.crypto.*")
public class TestA {

//Spying some things here & Injecting them

@Test
public void testA() {


   DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClientMock = PowerMockito.mock(DefaultHttpClient.class);
   HttpResponse httpResponse = PowerMockito.mock(HttpResponse.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
   HttpClient httpClient = PowerMockito.mock(HttpClient.class);
   //HttpResponse httpResponseMock    PowerMockito.mock(HttpResponse.class);
   HttpPost httpPost = PowerMockito.mock(HttpPost.class);
   PowerMockito.whenNew(DefaultHttpClient.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(defaultHttpClientMock);
   PowerMockito.doReturn(httpResponse).when(httpClient).execute(httpPost);      //Returns null. It never returns httpResponse.
   PowerMockito.when(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()).thenReturn(anyInt());
   //call the method
}
```

`PowerMockito.doReturn(httpResponse).when(httpClient).execute(httpPost)` always returns null. I want it to return the mock object of `HttpResponse`.
I have read other posts related to this error but not sure what to do in my case. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`PowerMockito.doReturn(httpResponse).when(httpClient).execute(httpPost);`

you should use

```
PowerMockito.when(httpResponse.execute(httpPost)).thenReturn(httpResponse);
```

You also have some problems in your test : incorrect mocking constructor and you don't need httpResponse  at all.

**Update** This code works correctly to me:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.crypto.*")
@PrepareForTest({ HttpPost.class, DefaultHttpClient.class, A.class })
public class TestA {

    @Test
    public void testA() throws Exception {
        HttpPost httpPost = Mockito.mock(HttpPost.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(HttpPost.class).withArguments(oAuthMessage.URL).thenReturn(httpPost);

        DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClientMock = PowerMockito.mock(DefaultHttpClient.class);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = PowerMockito.mock(HttpResponse.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(DefaultHttpClient.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(defaultHttpClientMock);

        PowerMockito.when(defaultHttpClientMock.execute(httpPost)).thenReturn(httpResponse);

        StatusLine statusLine = PowerMockito.mock(StatusLine.class);

        PowerMockito.when(httpResponse.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(statusLine);
        Integer expected = new Integer(0);
        PowerMockito.when(statusLine.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(expected);

        A a = new A();
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, a.callMethod());
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure of the line "incorrect mocking constructor and you don't need httpResponse at all." Can you please explain? @Evgeniy K.

Comment: Even after doing as you have suggested `PowerMockito.when(httpClient.execute(httpPost)).thenReturn(httpResponse)` is returning null.

Comment: @SumitPal Simply try and you see that code fails during execution method. How to mock constructor you can see on this site just search. You doing it wrong at least you need '@PrepareForTest({ HttpPost.class, DefaultHttpClient.class, A.class })' or rewrite code in class A to minimize count of calling constructor in method. About httpResponse - delete it at all and use defaultHttpClientMock.

Comment: Sorry I did not mention @PrepareForTest. I have written that in in my test class.

Comment: @SumitPal And you still have problem?

Comment: I have solved the problem. Now the problem comes in line 2. Using Mockito I am returning a mocked HttpResponse. Now how to deep stub this HttpResponse to get a mock code in the line `Integer code = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();`.  I have written `when(mockClient.execute(Matchers.any(HttpPost.class))).thenReturn(mockResponse);
HttpResponse httpResponse = Mockito.mock(HttpResponse.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);    when(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()).thenReturn(anyInt());` But this is not working.

Comment: @SumitPal I add code which works correctly to me and mocks what I want. Try and if it needed change your code.

Comment: Thanks Evgeniy. That worked perfectly. My concept was not clear in Mockito. Your answer helped a lot to improve it & clears all the question that I have in my mind. Thanks a lot :). @Evgeniy