# How to Mock RowMapper?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm trying to mock this dao and I'm getting a NPE. I'm not sure if I'm not mocking something correctly or I'm using something inappropriately. I have this dao below:

```
@Repository
public class PersonDaoImpl extends AbstractDao implements PersonDao {

    private static final String SQL = "select * from personTable";
    @Override
    public List<Person> getAllPerson() {
        PersonRowMapper personRowMapper = new PersonRowMapper ();
        List<Person> personList = getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(SQL, personRowMapper);

        return personList ;
    }
```

And this is my junit

```
public class PersonDaoImplTest {

    @Mock
    protected NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @Mock
    protected PersonRowMapper personRowMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    private PersonDaoImpl personDaoImpl;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnPerson() {
        when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(anyString(), Matchers.<RowMapper<PersonRowMapper>> any())).thenReturn(anyList());

        List<Person> resultList = personDaoImpl.getAllPerson();
        assertTrue(!resultList.isEmpty());
    }
```

It throws NPE on   `List<Person> resultList = personDaoImpl.getAllPerson();`

What am I missing or not mocking correctly? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It would be very hard to cover your code with test if you have constructors in methods.
You have several choices: rewrite code with Provider for PersonRowMapper  or mock constructor(PowerMock) or write matcher with argThat

Comment: @EvgeniyK. Can you provide an example of any of those three options? And why is hard to test with constructors in methods?

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it just be `Matchers.<PersonRowMapper>`?

```
when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(anyString(), Matchers.<PersonRowMapper> any())).thenReturn(anyList());
```

Comment: Still gives NPE

Comment: How about any(PersonRowMapper.class)

Answer (score 0):

First solution(with Provider).Recomended

```
    public class PersonDaoImpl extends AbstractDao implements PersonDao {

        private static final String SQL = "select * from personTable";

        com.google.inject.Provider<PersonRowMapper> provider;

        @Inject
        public PersonDaoImpl(Provider<PersonRowMapper> provider){
            this.provider = provider;
        }

        @Override
        public List<Person> getAllPerson() {
            PersonRowMapper personRowMapper = provider.get();
            List<Person> personList = getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(SQL);

            return personList ;
        }
```

In test

```
 public class PersonDaoImplTest {

       @Mock
       com.google.inject.Provider<PersonRowMapper> provider;
       ......

       @Test
       public void shouldReturnPerson() {
           when(provider.get()).thenReturn(personRowMapper);
       }
}
```

Second solution.

I am very lazy to write one more time how to mock constructors and just look on my answer on this topic [PowerMockito.doReturn returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38604848/powermockito-doreturn-returns-null) (or search on web) and you easily understand why it's hard to mock it and cover your code under unit tests. Guru of unit tests doesn't recommend mock constructor.