# Mocking private method call using PowerMockito returns null instead of returning List<String>: (Want not to execute private method)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, powermockito

I am trying to unit test a method using JUnit4. The method under test is calling another private method and I would like to mock it using PowerMockito.

My method is like below:

```
Class MyClass {
    public List<String> myMethod(String name) throws IOException
    {
       ... Few lines of code for setting variables
       List<String> result = myPrivateMethod(a, b);

       ... Few more lines of code..
       result.addAll(myPrivateMethod(c, d)); 

       return result;
    }

    private List<String> myPrivateMethod(String a, String b) {
    .....
    }
}
```

My unit test method to test above code is as below:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
public class TestClass {

  @Test
  public void testMyMethod() throws Exception {
    MyClass myClass = PowerMockito.spy(new MyClass());
    PowerMockito.doReturn(new ArrayList<String>(){{add("temp");}}).when(myClass, "myPrivateMethod", "a", "b");
    List<String> list = myClass.myMethod("someName");
    assertEquals(list.size(), 1);
  }
}
```

I am expecting line **PowerMockito.doReturn(new ArrayList(){{add("temp");}}).when(myClass, "myPrivateMethod", "a", "b");** to return list of size 1. I verified that execution is not going into private method but I am not getting List with one value added.

What is wrong in the above unit test code and why I am getting null instead of populated List as metioned in PowerMockito.doReturn() method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerMockito.doReturn returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38604848/powermockito-doreturn-returns-null)

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38604848/powermockito-doreturn-returns-null

Comment: @KavithaKarunakaran Thank you for your comment but from the above answers, it is asking to execute private methods and Mock objects/method call from the private method.

I am looking for an option not to execute a private method and just return a List<String> without executing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your test you are invoking `myMethod` which, in turn, invokes `myPrivateMethod` twice, see:

```
List<String> result = myPrivateMethod(a, b);
...
result.addAll(myPrivateMethod(c, d));
```

But your test only mocks one call to `myPrivateMethod` so the flow looks like this:

1. `myMethod` -> `myPrivateMethod` where the arguments are `a, b` - this **is** mocked and `myPrivateMethod` returns "temp"
2. `myMethod` -> `myPrivateMethod` where the arguments are `c, d` - this **is not** mocked and hence `myPrivateMethod` is executed

In order for this assertion to pass: `assertEquals(list.size(), 1);`  you'll need to rework your test to mock the second call to `myPrivateMethod`. In addition, the reference to "returns null" suggest that the `when` block here: `.when(myClass, "myPrivateMethod", "a", "b")` did not match the actual parameters supplied in your `myMethod`.

Here's a working example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public List<String> myMethod(String name) throws IOException {
        List<String> result = myPrivateMethod("a", "b");
        result.addAll(myPrivateMethod("c", "d"));
        return result;
    }

    private List<String> myPrivateMethod(String a, String b) {
        List<String> r = new ArrayList<>();
        r.add(a);
        r.add(b);
        return r;
    }
}

@Test
public void testMyMethod() throws Exception {
    MyClass myClass = PowerMockito.spy(new MyClass());

    PowerMockito.doReturn(new ArrayList<String>(){{add("temp");}})
        .when(myClass, "myPrivateMethod", "a", "b");

    PowerMockito.doReturn(new ArrayList<String>())
        .when(myClass, "myPrivateMethod", "c", "d");

    List<String> list = myClass.myMethod("someName");
    assertEquals(1, list.size());
    assertEquals("temp", list.get(0));
}
```

The above example test passes with the following:

- junit: 4.12
- powermock-module-junit4: 2.0.2
- powermock-api-mockito2: 2.0.2